# Telephone Word Generator Implementation in Swift based on C# Program

Tags: ios, swift, ms-word, numbers

I'm currently trying to implement the Telephone word generator. I looked all around the web for something that I could use and this is what I found.

I found this implementation in C#:

```cs
public static void printPhoneWords(int[] number) {
     char[] output = new char[number.length];
     printWordsUtil(number,0,output);
}

static String[] phoneKeys= new String[]{"0", "1", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL",
               "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ"};
private static void printWordsUtil(int[] number, int curDigIndex, char[] output) {
    // Base case, if current output word is done
    if (curDigIndex == output.length) {
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(output) + " "); 
        return;
    }
  // Try all 3-4 possible characters for the current digit in number[]
  // and recurse for the remaining digits

char curPhoneKey[] = phoneKeys[number[curDigIndex]].toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i< curPhoneKey.length ; i++) {
    output[curDigIndex] = curPhoneKey[i];
    printWordsUtil(number, curDigIndex+1, output);
    if (number[curDigIndex] <= 1) // for 0 or 1
        return;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number[] = {2, 3, 4};
    printPhoneWords(number);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now, I tried to implement it in Swift, but I'm getting a few issues..

```
var pinDict = [2:"abc", 3:"def", 4:"ghi", 5:"jkl", 6:"mno", 7:"pqrs", 8:"tuv", 9:"wxyz"]


func printWordsUtil(number: [Int], curDigIndex: Int, output: Array<Character>) {

    var curPhoneKey:Array<Character> = []

    curPhoneKey = pinDict[number[curDigIndex]]

    for var i = 0; i < curPhoneKey.count; i++ {
        output[curDigIndex] = pinDict[i]
        printWordsUtil(number, curDigIndex+1, output)
        if(number[curDigIndex] <= 1) {
            return
        }
    }
}
func printPhoneWords(number: [Int]) {
    var output:Array<Character> = []
    printWordsUtil(number,0,output)
}
func main() {
    var number = [2, 2, 7, 3]
    printPhoneWords(number)
}
```

I'm getting my errors here:

- `curPhoneKey = pinDict[number[curDigIndex]]`      // `'(Int, String)'` not convertible to `'Array<Character>'` Not sure how to solve this...
- `output[curDigIndex] = pinDict[i]`                // `'@lvalue $T8'` is not identical to 'Character'

Any ideas on how to have this implementation working in Swift?

Ok, so at the moment I have this:

```
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[a!])
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[b!])
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[c!])
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[d!])
func combos<T>(var array: Array<T>, k: Int) -> Array<Array<T>> {
    if k == 0 { return [[]] } if array.isEmpty { return [] }
    let head = [array[0]]
    let subcombos = combos(array, k - 1)
    var ret = subcombos.map {head + $0} 
    array.removeAtIndex(0)
    ret += combos(array, k) 
    return ret 
}
combos(comparisonArray, 4)
```

The comparison array is `["ABC, "DEF", "DEF, "PQRS"]` . Now, how do you permute every letter in each combination on it's own instead of permuting the element, so it looks like this? `["A", "D", "D", "P"]`, `["B", "D", "D", "P"]` ? THANKS!

Comment: Your pinDict is defined as Int:String (i.e int key maps to string value) but your assigning the value to an Array<Character>. You need to convert from String to this array type if you want to use it. Strings are not arrays in Swift. Second error is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need this string extension:

```
extension String {
    subscript (index:Int) -> String { return String(Array(self)[index]) }
}
```

First lets convert the Int Array to a String Array

```
func intArrayToStringArray(number: [Int]) -> [String] {
    if number.isEmpty { return [] }
    let keyboard = ["0","1","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"]        var result:[String] = []
    for i in 0..<number.count {
        result.append(keyboard[number[i]])
    }
    return result
}

let firstStep = intArrayToStringArray([2,2,7,3])  //  ["abc", "abc", "pqrs", "def"]
```

Then we will need to nest one loop for each number and pick the letters using the index combination of them, join them using string interpolation and append it to the output array.

```
func secontStep(input:[String]) -> [String] {
    var output:[String] = []
    for w in 0..<countElements(input[0]) {
        for x in 0..<countElements(input[1]) {
            for y in 0..<countElements(input[2]){
                for z in 0..<countElements(input[3]){
                    output.append("\(input[0][w])\(input[1][x])\(input[2][y])\(input[3][z)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output
}
let wordsArray = secontStep(firstStep) // ["aapd", "aape", "aapf", "aaqd", "aaqe", "aaqf", "aard", "aare", "aarf", "aasd", "aase", "aasf", "abpd", "abpe", "abpf", "abqd", "abqe", "abqf", "abrd", "abre", "abrf", "absd", "abse", "absf", "acpd", "acpe", "acpf", "acqd", "acqe", "acqf", "acrd", "acre", "acrf", "acsd", "acse", "acsf", "bapd", "bape", "bapf", "baqd", "baqe", "baqf", "bard", "bare", "barf", "basd", "base", "basf", "bbpd", "bbpe", "bbpf", "bbqd", "bbqe", "bbqf", "bbrd", "bbre", "bbrf", "bbsd", "bbse", "bbsf", "bcpd", "bcpe", "bcpf", "bcqd", "bcqe", "bcqf", "bcrd", "bcre", "bcrf", "bcsd", "bcse", "bcsf", "capd", "cape", "capf", "caqd", "caqe", "caqf", "card", "care", …, "cbqe", "cbqf", "cbrd", "cbre", "cbrf", "cbsd", "cbse", "cbsf", "ccpd", "ccpe", "ccpf", "ccqd", "ccqe", "ccqf", "ccrd", "ccre", "ccrf", "ccsd", "ccse", "ccsf"]
```

the opposite would be like this:

```
func stringToArray(var number: String) -> [Int] {
    if number == "" { return [] }
    number = number.lowercaseString
    var result:[Int] = []
    for i in 0..<countElements(number) {
        if number[i] == "0" { result.append(0) }
        if number[i] == "1" { result.append(1) }
        if number[i] == "2" || number[i] == "a" || number[i] == "b" || number[i] == "c"                     { result.append(2) }
        if number[i] == "3" || number[i] == "d" || number[i] == "e" || number[i] == "f"                     { result.append(3) }
        if number[i] == "4" || number[i] == "g" || number[i] == "h" || number[i] == "i"                     { result.append(4) }
        if number[i] == "5" || number[i] == "j" || number[i] == "k" || number[i] == "l"                     { result.append(5) }
        if number[i] == "6" || number[i] == "m" || number[i] == "n" || number[i] == "o"                     { result.append(6) }
        if number[i] == "7" || number[i] == "p" || number[i] == "q" || number[i] == "r" || number[i] == "s" { result.append(7) }
        if number[i] == "8" || number[i] == "t" || number[i] == "u" || number[i] == "v"                     { result.append(8) }
        if number[i] == "9" || number[i] == "w" || number[i] == "x" || number[i] == "y" || number[i] == "z" { result.append(9) }
    }
    return result
}
stringToArray("1800HELLO")  // [1, 8, 0, 0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6]
stringToArray("1800hello")  // [1, 8, 0, 0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Right yeah, I understand what you did there, but what I need here is to get all possible combinations for that 4 digit entry. So for example the results would be: 'aapd', 'badd', 'cadd' and onwards iterating through every letter. That's what I'm stuck on haha. I have an array on the other hand with the most commonly used words. So it will try to compare if any of those words are in the word dictionary. For example the function will do all the possible iterations and then try and find 'care' which is in the word dictionary and is the same as 2273

Comment: Ok I got it I will think how I would implement that.

Comment: Ok, so at the moment I have this: `comparisonArray.append(dictionary[a!])
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[b!])
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[c!])
comparisonArray.append(dictionary[d!])

func combos<T>(var array: Array<T>, k: Int) -> Array<Array<T>> {
    if k == 0 {
        return [[]]
    }
    
    if array.isEmpty {
        return []
    }
    
    let head = [array[0]]
    let subcombos = combos(array, k - 1)
    var ret = subcombos.map {head + $0}
    array.removeAtIndex(0)
    ret += combos(array, k)
    
    return ret
}

combos(comparisonArray, 4)`

Comment: The comparison array is `["ABC, "DEF", "DEF, "PQRS"]` . Now, how do you permute every letter in each combination on it's own instead of permuting the element, so it looks like this? `["A", "D", "D", "P"]`, `["B", "D", "D", "P"]` ? THANKS!

Comment: Can you show me what you've got? Might be able to figure something out of it. 4^6 is 4096. That's weird.

Comment: "abc"x"abc"x"pqrs"x"def" = 3x3x4x3 = 128 different combinations.

Comment: It is done. It was pretty simple. As you can see all I needed was to nest de loops and used that extension string subscript to get the characters from the strings.

Comment: So it will always return from 81 to 256 combinations depending on the input. Minimum would be 3x3x3x3 that would generate 81 different combinations and the maximum would be 4x4x4x4 that will generate 256 different combinations.